# send information through intent.putExtra()

Tags: android

i found  several thread "title like me "but my qus is diffrent .my qus is using intent can i send the data to only next calling activity?can i dont use that getExtra() method in other activity means can i get the data in any activity via using "key"?

as for example...

```
     int number=5;   
     Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
     i.putExtra("numbers", number);
     startActivity(i);


     In the activity B i get the info:


     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     int arrayB = extras.getInt("numbers");
```

can i get it in any other activity also...?

Comment: hm... you should probably tell us what you're trying to achieve. Maybe use sendBroadcast() ?

Comment: exactly i dont know what should i use for achieving the same..but i want transfer one activity variable/object data to any other class related to same package so how to achieve this ?i know "static" key word also one option but i heard its not good so what should be use..thanks for res poncing again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. you cannot get this in another activity unless you can not send this intent to that Activity.

An Intent object is a bundle of information. when you startActivity we pass the information to that activity. If you want to use this bundle into another activity you have pass to that activity.

you can do to pass the bundle of information as the level like

A->B->C

here Activity A start the activity and pass the information to the B Activity and same bundle you can pass to the C Activity as you send directly A->C

Comment: hey pratik ,if we are sending from a->c then we have to get it on "B" and again put it on intent ?right?pls

Comment: A->B->C and A->C that are different. In A->C no B Activity was called or used here.

Answer (score 1):

your intent will only reference one activity (in this case, B.activity.class) so only B will be able to pull up the extras.

if a third activity C requires the info, you will need to structure your program such that B will call another intent (C.class) passing the same extras down.

Answer (score 1):

as your code suggests,

```
 int number=5;   
 Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
 i.putExtra("numbers", number);
 startActivity(i);
```

and from the line

```
 Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
```

your bundle object get the resources in only B activity.

EDIT: you get the bundle object in only that activity for which you had pass the intent.
      so, only that activity receive it.

And if you want to access data in other activity make use of shared preference, sqlite, internal storage file etc..

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to achieve this using [`sendBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) from the `Activity` that wants to send data to multiple `Activities`  and by registering [`BroadcastReceivers`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) inside the `Activities` that you want to receive the `Intent`. You can have a look at this tutorial [Basic of Android: Intent Receivers](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-ii-intent-receivers/) to get a start on `BroadcastReceivers`.